# Toggle language using one button

Tags: php, toggle, lang

I'm trying to make one-button language switch using qtranslate and different url mydomain.com/en/ etc. ), but with PHP I'm unable to do that, since it takes just a first (loading document) state.

```
<div class="language-box">
<?php if (get_locale() == 'en_EN') { ?>
<a href="/en/" class="lang en">
<img src="<?php echo get_template_directory_uri(); ?>-child/imgs/lang-czech.png"/>
<?php } else { ?>
<a href="/cs" class="lang cz">
<img src="<?php echo get_template_directory_uri(); ?>-child/imgs/lang-english.png"/> 
<?php } ?>
</a>
</div>
```

Comment: just wondering if there is any other solution, than making two buttons and hiding/revealing them vice versa

Comment: So you want one button that is dynamic depending on the current language? Instead of having multiple <a> tags?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
<?php

$lang = get_locale();
$href = "cz";
$img = "english";

switch ($lang){
    case "en_EN":
        $href = "en";
        $img = "czech";
        break;     
    default:
        $href = "cz";
        $img = "english";
        break;
}

?>

<div class="language-box">
    <a href="/<?php echo $href; ?>/" class="lang <?php echo $href; ?>">
        <img src="<?php echo get_template_directory_uri(); ?>-child/imgs/lang-<?php echo $img; ?>.png"/>
    </a>
</div>
```

Comment: it works without default condition, i've used two cases instead

Comment: You're welcome. And since you are not too concerned about dealing with multiple languages, you could do:
$lang = get_locale();
$href = ($lang == "en_EN")?"en":"cz";
$img = ($lang == "en_EN")?"czech":"english";